# Regex: match several not obligated lines

Tags: c#, regex

I'm sorry for not very clear title(

Let me explain the details below.

I have a file with next lines:

```
...
09-05-2023 13:15. Feature. Test ticket. #OW72-59

  New feature description.

  Second line of new feature.

09-05-2023 13:15. Bug. Weird bug is here. #OW72-58
...
```

Every item has mandatory fixed part (`09-05-2023 13:15. Feature. Test ticket. #OW72-59`, for example)

and not mandatory part (  `New feature description.  Second line of new feature.`, for example).

Not mandatory part may be multiline and always formatted with two leading spaces on every line. But I think I can this format if it will help.

My current regex (https://regex101.com/r/HTdvjN/1) matches regular part very well. But I can't match partial part correctly.

```
(?'date'\d*-\d*-\d*\s*\d*[:]?\d*). (?'tag'\w*). (?'desc'\w.*). #(?<issueId>.*?-\d*)
```

I can change the format of the file if necessary.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please add sample text and attempted regex as part of your question instead of showing an image

Comment: Your regex matches `--. . _. #-`. Are you sure you want it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with your specifications:

```bash
(?'date'\d+-\d+-\d+\s*\d*:?\d+)\. (?'tag'\w+)\. (?'desc'\w.*)\. #(?<issueId>\w+-\d+)(?'feature'(?:[\r\n]+  .*)*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HTdvjN/2)

Important change is this part to capture multiline :

```bash
(?'feature'(?:[\r\n]+  .*)*)
```

This pattern matches line break followed by a line that starts with 2 spaces. Repeat this group 0 or more times to allow matching empty text or multiple lines.